# ListBox Grouping issue

Tags: wpf, listbox, itemscontrol

I am trying to Group my collection which is based on my following model:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Role PersonRole { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
}
```

My PersonCollection,

```
public ObservableCollection<Person> PersonList;
```

The collection is populated with three Person object, two with identical roles.

I want to group all my persons as per their RoleName. I have the following XAML:

```
<Grid.Resources>

        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs" Source="{Binding PersonList}">
            <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="PersonRole.RoleName"/>
            </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>

    </Grid.Resources>

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ListBox.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PersonRole.RoleName}" FontWeight="Bold" Background="ForestGreen" Margin="0,5,0,0"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListBox.GroupStyle>
    </ListBox>
```

However the rendered UI is not displaying the grouped RoleName in the list box. Also I would like to show the grouping horizontally where the groups appear horizontally while the grouped items appear vertically. Appreciate any help in advance.

Here's the output I am seeing:
[image]

Comment: You want alot... ;) Post us your example so we can work it.

Comment: Well, actually I am just trying to figure out why the RoleName is not being shown. Horizontal grouping is though a secondary concern.

Comment: Just post code. I dont want to work my way though all the templates and test data. You have them already.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since you have already provided `GroupDescriptons` at your CollectionViewSource, groupStyle will pick the property name from there only.

All you need is to **bind with `Name` property of `CollectionViewGroup` class** to access the value of the property on which grouping is applied. In group style, binding is against CollectionViewGroup class and not against your Model class.

So, this is how you will do it:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold"
           Background="ForestGreen" Margin="0,5,0,0"/>
```

And regarding to align groups horizontally, you can set `ItemsPanelTemplate` of Group to be `VirtualizingStackPanel` with `Orientation` set to `Horizontal` which makes your groups to be aligned horizontally.

```
<ListBox.GroupStyle>
   <GroupStyle>
      <GroupStyle.Panel>
         <ItemsPanelTemplate>
           <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
         </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </GroupStyle.Panel>
      <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold"
                      Background="ForestGreen" Margin="0,5,0,0"/>
         </DataTemplate>
      </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
   </GroupStyle>
</ListBox.GroupStyle>
```

Comment: Thanks, Rohit. Your explanation made it real easy for me to understand.

Comment: Voted up because it solved an unrelated problem haha. Thanks ;)