# Ideas for how to make a date separator (Today/Tomorrow) for a mail inbox like application?

Tags: wpf, datetime, mvvm, binding

So I have an application that is sort of like an e-mail inbox, and I'm trying to create a separator for each day. The messages are already sorted by date (newest to oldest), but I want to make a line to divide them up by dates, and possibly add the dates on top of the lines. The messages are stored in a ViewModel and are presented with a DataTemplate. I can't think of a good way to create this functionality and still maintain the MVVM aspect.

My thoughts so far would be to somehow store a date value and when this value is different than the previous, I would insert a new separator. Then keep going through the messages until I find one with a different date, then add a new separator and so on and so forth.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type MessageViewModel}">
 <StackPanel>
  <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Date}"/> <!-- Only show this when it's a new date -->
  <Path Data="m 0 0 200 0"/> <!-- Only show this when it's a new date -->
  <Grid>
   <!-- Message name, sender and stuff goes here -->
  </Grid>
 </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Do I have to make a new ViewModel of some sort to store these DateValues and do a comparison through a Converter or through Triggers?

Comment: You may want to use ListBox/ListView Grouping.

Comment: You mean to group DataTemplates based on Dates in?

Comment: Search StackOverflow or the web for *ListBox Grouping*, e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21835902/listbox-grouping-issue

Comment: Another option to consider would be to use a hierarchy or list within list. A treeview is intended for hierarchical data and you could manipulate the data so it has messages as a collection of a day object. Or even a tabcontrol with a tab per day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind to a grouped `CollectionView` and define a `GroupStyle` as explained here: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-grouping/.

The separator would be part of the `GroupStyle`'s `ContainerStyle`. You would also add a new `PropertyGroupDescription("Date)` to the `GroupDescriptions` collection of the `CollectionView`, where "Date" is the name of your email model's date property.

You might also choose create a `CollectionViewSource` in the view and bind to this one:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Name="cvs" Source="{Binding ViewModelCollection}">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Date" />
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</Window.Resources>

<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}">
    ...
</ListView>
```

Comment: Thanks! This got me quite far, I did some reading, and then some more reading. Eventually I figured out I could use CollectionViewSource part for the grouping and still stick with my old ItemsControl layout, and this seems to be working. The only problem is the Dates are all different (as in the timestamps are, not the calendar date), so I can't use it like it is. Is there a way to use stringformat on the PropertyName, or do I have to use a converter?

Comment: I am not sure that you mean by "stringformat on the PropertyName". But please ask a new question if you have another issue.

Comment: It's still a part of this question. Because now it groups them after Date and Time (DateTime). And if I have 10 messages in one day, they are all very likely to have come at different times, so I end up with 10 groups. Ideally I would have used a stringformat of ("ddmmyy") or similar to only group based on days. but since the PropertyGroupDescription PropertyNames does not use a binding it seems like I can't use the StringFormat parameter on "Date"

Comment: You could add another property to your data object where the DateTime property is defined and group by this one.

Comment: That's a good idea, and probably less expensive than a converter. Thanks!